# How to copy lines between two strings to a new text file matching first string fully and second string partially

Tags: bash

This is how my file input.txt looks like

```
$cat input.txt

*NODE_SET
a
b
c
d
*NODE
e
f
g
h
*XYZ
```

Now I want to output lines between *NODE  until it encounters another line containing "*"  to a new file "output.txt".
i.e. output.txt should contain:

```
*NODE
e
f
g
h
*XYZ
```

The problem here is *XYZ can be any unknown string; i.e. it can be *ELEMENT, *LOAD etc but star exists in t he begning of the line.

Comment: Do you have to do this once or repeatedly? That makes a lot of difference for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sed should work:

```
sed -n '/^\*NODE$/,/^*/p' input.txt > output.txt
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
*NODE
e
f
g
h
*XYZ
```

Comment: What if I want just  
*NODE  
e  
f  
g  
h

Comment: You're welcome. For `*NODE e f g h` you can use: `sed -n '/^*NODE e f g h/,/^*/p'`

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. What I meant was What if I don't want *XYZ in teh output.

Comment: Then you will need: `sed -n '/^*NODE$/,/^*/{$d;p;}'`